# Where is the state of a Electron-Vue application stored?

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex

**How and, more to the point, where is state data persisted between sessions?**

I followed this tutorial (https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-electron/) to create a simple ToDo App using Vue.js in Electron.

After filling in some blanks everything works. However, I'm unable to find where the application state is stored. For example, in Dev mode (`npm run dev`), if I add some ToDo items and then close the App (and even restart VS Code) the ToDo data is persisted when the App is restarted.

I'm using Win10 and, among other things, have tried searching for files changed within the last 30 minutes (`datemodified:‎23/‎09/‎2019 12:30..13:00`) but without luck. I've looked in my profile, the App directory, and searched google for clues.

[Edit]

I think it has something to do with this `import { createPersistedState, createSharedMutations } from 'vuex-electron'` (located in src\renderer\store\index.js) but not much closer to understanding where the state is stored. Yep - I'm pretty new to this.

---

**For what it's worth, if you want to follow this tutorial:**

**Issue 1.**

> Now that we know how the Vue application is started, let’s take a look at the defined routes within our application. Head over to src/router/index.js:

should be: src/***renderer***/router/index.js:

**Issue 2.** In src/renderer/components/LandingPage.vue

> ```js
>      <div class="todos">
>       <ul>
>         <li
>           class="todo-item"
>           v-for="todo in todos"
>           :key="todo.id"
>           @click="completeTodo(todo)"></li>
>       </ul>
>     </div>
> ```

should be:

```js
    <div class="todos">
      <ul>
        <li
          class="todo-item"
          v-for="todo in todos"
          :key="todo.id"
          @click="completeTodo(todo)">{{todo.name}}</li>  // {{todo.name}}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using 'createPersistedState' option of 'vuex-electon' saves in json format in 'AppData' path.

```
uerName/AppData/Roaming/Electron/vuex.json
```

Remove 'createPersistedState' to disable saving.

```
import { createSharedMutations } from 'vuex-electron'

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules,
  plugins: [
    createSharedMutations()
  ],
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

see a https://github.com/vue-electron/vuex-electron

Comment: And... there it is, thank you. I hadn't looked in Roaming - if you don't mind can you edit your answer to explain how I could have discovered this for myself? Is there a link to some documentation or perhaps a clue in the source code?

Comment: `electron-vue` template was used in the tutorial and `vuex-electron` was used in this `electron-vue` template. Therefore, refer to the `vuex-electron`.

Comment: Thank you for that link, I guess I'm missing something obvious. I had a look at readme for vuex-electron and also through some of the corresponding source code but still can't find what I'm looking for.  Also, I can't find where the state is persisted for the built version of the App. Appreciate your help.