# How to change button property when starting a vuex-electron app?

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex

I am working on a vuex-electron application.
There are several buttons on the main page, when clicked, a file is stored in a specific folder, and at the same time, the property of the button turns to [saved], when this [saved] button is clicked again, a message pops up, asking whether to overwrite or not the old file.
But the problem is : when the app is restarted, all of the buttons' property is initialized to [not saved], so, even though the same file has already been stored, when button is clicked, the old file is overwritten without any pop-ups asking whether to overwrite the existing file or not.

I want to change the feature as below:
when the app is restarted, check file existence first, then based on the result, change button property to [saved].
Is this possible?
If possible, where should I add the logic in.

I am a complete beginner on vue.js.
Have been looking up for a while, but did not find any useful information.

From the following thread, learned that state data is stored in a json file, does this mean I need to change the state? Currently, button properties are not saved in this json file.

[Where is the state of a Electron-Vue application stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055227/where-is-the-state-of-a-electron-vue-application-stored)

//code

```js
    v-for="(btn,i) in buttons" :key="i" @click="save(btn)"
    
    
    computed: {
            buttons() {
                let r = this.$store.state.App.aData.filter(x=> {
                    if (this.aType==='abc') {
                        return x.video.toString() === '1'
                    } else {
                        return !x.video
                    }
                }).map(x => {
                    let y = this.$copy(x)
                    y.saved = this.savedData.includes(x.index)
                    y.disabled = this.appState !== 'def'
                    return y
                })
                let index = this.aType==='abc'?998:999
                r.push({
                    index,
                    a_name:'others',
                    e_number:this.aType==='abc'?'N':'999',
                    disabled: this.appState !== 'def',
                    saved: this.savedData.includes(index),
                    video:''
                })
                return r
            },
    },
    
    methods:{
            save(btn) {
                if (btn.disabled) {
                    return
                }
                if (btn.saved) {
                    this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
                        message: '??',
                        confirmText: 'overwrite?',
                        cancelText: 'cancel',
                        type: 'is-danger',
                        hasIcon: true,
                        onConfirm: () => {
                            if (this.aType==='xyz') {
                                this.saveXyz(btn)
                            }
                            if (this.aType==='abc') {
                                this.saveAbc(btn)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    return
                }
                if (this.aType==='xyz') {
                    this.saveXyz(btn)
                }
                if (this.shootingType==='abc') {
                    this.saveAbc(btn)
                }
            },
            
            
            saveXyz(data) {
                if (this.xyzBuffer) {
                    //create a file and store to a folder
                            this.savedData.push(data.index)
                            let idx = this.$store.state.App.aData.findIndex(x=>x.index===data.index)
                            if (idx > -1) {
                                idx++
                                if (idx < this.$store.state.App.aData.length) {
                                    this.selectedData = idx
                                    this.aType = this.$store.state.App.aData[this.selectedData].video ? 'abc' : 'xyz'
                                    this.scrollTo(this.selectedData)
                                }
                            }
                            this.cancel()
                        })
                    }
                }
            },
            
                saveAbc(data) {
                if (this.recording) {
                    return
                }
                //create a file and store to a folder
                        this.savedData.push(data.index)
                        let idx = this.$store.state.App.aData.findIndex(x=>x.index===data.index)
                        if (idx > -1) {
                            idx++
                            if (idx < this.$store.state.App.aData.length) {
                                this.selectedData = idx
                                this.aType = this.$store.state.App.aData[this.selectedData].video ? 'abc' : 'xyz'
                                this.scrollTo(this.selectedData)
                            }
                        }
                        this.cancel()
                    }
    
                })
            },
            
    },
```

Comment: To be able to help you properly, it would be nice if you put some of your code so that we can understand your approach and your code logic better. Otherwise, it will be difficult to help you integrate an answer.

Comment: @fchancel Thank you. I have added some of the code that I think is relevant.